# How can I create my own texture map for ThreeJS material?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a fbx model which implements a UV map to texture the model. The model consists of a single mesh which should be colored using 4 quadrants like so:

[image]

So, I need to create a MeshToonMaterial with a map like so: `const material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ map: texture });`

I'm wondering how I can create this texture.

Here is what I have so far, however, it is not working as intended. The entire material is black:

```
const createUVTexture = () => {
    const width = 2;
    const height = 2;
    const size = width * height;
    const getColor = (i, j) => {
      if (i === 0 && j === 0) { // quad 1
        return { // white
          r: 1,
          g: 1,
          b: 1
        }
      } 

      if (i === 0 && j === 1) { // quad 2
        return { // green
          r: 0,
          g: 1,
          b: 0
        }
      }

      if (i === 1 && j === 0) { // quad 3
        return { // blue
          r: 0,
          g: 0,
          b: 1
        }
      }

      if (i === 1 && j === 1) { // quad 4
        return {
          r: 1,
          g: 0,
          b: 0
        }
      }
    }
    const data = new Uint8Array( 4 * size );
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++){
      for (let j = 0; j < width; j++){
        const stride = (i * height + j) * 4;
        const { r, g, b } = getColor(i, j);
        data[stride] = r;
        data[stride + 1] = g;
        data[stride + 2] = b;
        data[stride + 3] = 1;
      }
    }
    const texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, width, height);
    const material = new THREE.MeshToonMaterial({ map: texture });
    return material;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a `DataTexture` expects the color information to be an integer in the `[0, 255]` range. The data you're passing is from `[0, 1]`, which makes it almost entirely black. Just multiply your data by 255, and you should be able to see the color. This is actually the same approach demonstrated in [the DataTexture documentation page](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=texture#api/en/textures/DataTexture):

```js
data[stride + 0] = Math.floor(r * 255);
data[stride + 1] = Math.floor(g * 255);
data[stride + 2] = Math.floor(b * 255);
data[stride + 3] = 255;
```